# Getting Specific Google Analytics Goal Funnel Stage

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get specific goal stages values..
But I am only able to get
With the API Expolorer

the startGoal and Goal Completed (Look at the picture I've attached to understand what I'm unable to get)
With the

> ga:goal1Start

I am able to get the number: **15,963(Look at the picture ive attached to understand)**

and with the

> ga:goal1Completions

I am able to get the number: **31(Look at the picture ive attached to understand)**

[image: Goal Stages Image]

How can I get the middle stages at the goals with the value 156? 
Is that even possible?

Api Explorer:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.ga.get?ids=ga%253A68044380&start-date=2013-02-20&end-date=2013-02-20&metrics=ga%253Agoal1Starts%252C+ga%253Agoal1Completions&_h=24&!

Comment: Add a second goal (either Url goal or add an event to that page) ? Or, since it seems impossible to enter the page from outside the goal funnel, you could simply query the url for that page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those in-between numbers are not directly accessible through the API - neither the typical GA API nor the new Multi Channel Funnels API. The Multi Channel Funnels API deals with users visiting from multiple sources (or 'channels') before completing a goal, so the 'funnel' in its name actually refers to a different type of funnel than the one we are concerned with here -- a funnel of pageviews within one visit.

Although these intermediate numbers are not available through the API directly, we can use the API and some documentation-based knowledge to calculate them.

This [Google Analytics documentation](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2976313) gives great information on how the Funnel Visualization report is calculated. I'll refer to sections of this document for clarity in calculating the numbers that you see at intermediate steps, because these numbers are not as simple as pageviews or visits to that step.

Looking at your funnel, I believe that you have selected the "Required 1st Step" option. I'll go through the explanation without this option first, and then explain how we can modify our process to take the required first step into consideration. I'll model your funnel as Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3 > Completion, and I'll assume we want the number associated with Step 3. The process would be similar for Step 2.

### Without Required First Step

We need to gather the following information from the API. To do so, you should create advanced segments to match these populations in the GA interface, and then use the segments in the API by [numeric id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#segment):

1. Number of visits to the URL associated with Step 3 (see documentation, "Unique Pageviews").
2. Number of visits to the Completion URL who did not visit Step 3, as the funnel visualization report will backfill these visits (see documentation, "Backfilling Funnel Steps).

**Advanced Segment for Completion Visits without Step 3**
[image: Advanced Segment for Completion Visits without Step 3]

Then add the results of 1 and 2 together.

### With Required First Step

You'll collect the same information as in Steps 1 and 2 above, but you'll extend the advanced segments to require that the visit includes Step 1 as well.

**Advanced Segment for Step 3 Visits, Step 1 Required**
[image: Advanced Segment for Step 3 Visits, Step 1 Required]

Comment: Can you link me to the page you show in the pictures? or even if you could an example code in PHP. since im having hard time to figure out how to make it work..

Comment: The API tool that I used throughout my example was [GA Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/). I'm not much of a PHP guy, but there are some resources out there for the PHP API. For the pictures in my example, check out this [information on creating advanced segments](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033017).

Answer (score -2):

You cannot get this information by accessing the normal Google Analytics API, but there is another API called "Multi Channel Funnel" API (more precisely: [Conversion Paths - Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/conversionpaths)) that should let you extract the data you're looking for. I have only used the `ga:` calls so far myself, but it is my understanding that this is exactly what the `mcf:` calls are for.

Comment: Multi Channel Funnel (MCF) API will not give you this information.  The MCF features are something completely different than the funnel visualization asked about in this question.  MCF is for doing attribution analysis (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1191180?hl=en).  Funnel visualization is for understanding user behavior prior to completing (or abandoning) a goal.  It is confusing that the word "funnel" is used in both.

Comment: @MarkHansen Thank you for clarifying, I misunderstood the purpose of MCF.